# Updating MongoDB Database From Client Side

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm making something of a quiz app, and I'm creating an edit page for each quiz ID to edit the specific question/answer.
However, the QuizID always returns as undefined at the end of an edit.

I've tried switching between"id" and "_id". I'm using the findByIDAndUpdate method

This is the part of the app.js

```
app.get('/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const quizId = req.params.id; // Assuming the ID is passed as a route parameter
        const quiz = await Quiz.findById(quizId); // Fetch the quiz item from MongoDB
        res.render('editQuizID', { quiz }); // Render the edit form with the quiz details
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.redirect('/'); // Redirect  to handle errors
    }
});

app.post("/completeEdit", function (req, res) {
    const quizId = req.params.id; // Access the ID from the form submission
    const editedQuestion = req.body.editQuestion;
    const editedAnswer = req.body.editAnswer;

    console.log(editedQuestion, editedAnswer)

    const updateDocument = async (quizId) => {
        try {
            const updatedResult = await Quiz.findByIdAndUpdate(
                quizId,
                {
                    question: editedQuestion,
                    answer: editedAnswer
                },
                { new: true }
            );
            if (updatedResult) {
                console.log("Quiz updated:", updatedResult);
                res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                console.log("Quiz not found.", quizId);
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    };

    updateDocument(quizId)

});

app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log("Server running on port 4000");
});
```

This is the ejs file for the edit page

```
<h1>Make An Edit</h1>
<form action="/completeEdit" method="post">
    <div class="edit-window-content">
      <label>Question</label>
      <input class="question-edit-box" type="text" name="editQuestion" placeholder="Edit question" value="<%= quiz.question %>">

      <label>Answer</label>
      <textarea class="answer-edit-box" type="text" name="editAnswer" rows="4" cols="30" placeholder="Edit answer"><%= quiz.answer %></textarea>
      
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= quiz.id %>">
      <button class="overlay-close" type="submit" name="button">Done</button>
    </div>
  </form
```

Comment: The second `const quizId = req.params.id;` (which is in `app.post`) doesn't seem right, you haven't defined it in the route. Please re-check the code and also provide which line that the error got thrown from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can't access a parameter from `req.params` if it is not included in the route handler definition. I can see you are sending the `id` in your form submission here:

```js
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= quiz.id %>">
```

So inside of your route handler just extract it from `req.body` instead.

Secondly you don't need to define an `updateDocument` function just to call it on the next line, just make your route handler callback function `async`. A finished route handler with these changes might look like:

```js
app.post("/completeEdit", async function (req, res) { //< Mark as async
   const quizId = req.body.id; //< change to this
   const editedQuestion = req.body.editQuestion;
   const editedAnswer = req.body.editAnswer;

   console.log(editedQuestion, editedAnswer)
   try {
      const updatedResult = await Quiz.findByIdAndUpdate(
         quizId,
         {
            question: editedQuestion,
            answer: editedAnswer
         },
         { new: true }
      );
      if (updatedResult) {
         console.log("Quiz updated:", updatedResult);
         res.redirect('/');
      } else {
         console.log("Quiz not found.", quizId);
         res.redirect('/');
      }
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.redirect('/');
   }
});
```